# RadioButton Not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have strange problem with `radio button`. I used `UIButton` for `radio button` and used two image `btnCheck.png` and `btnUnCheck.png` in normal case its working properly there is no problem. this is my code on button click

```
   -(IBAction)btnNextClick:(id)sender {
      UIImage* selectedImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"];
      if ((btnILink.imageView.image == selectedImg  || btnTapeIn.imageView.image == selectedImg || btnKeraLink.imageView.image == selectedImg))
      {
        if (btnTapeIn.imageView.image == selectedImg) {
            UIImage* selectedImg1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"];
            if (!(btn18.imageView.image == selectedImg1 || btn22.imageView.image == selectedImg1)){
                [FunctionManager showMessage:@"" withMessage:@"Please Select Length" withDelegage:nil];
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            UIImage* selectedImg1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"];
            if (!(btn16.imageView.image == selectedImg1  || btn18.imageView.image == selectedImg1 || btn22.imageView.image == selectedImg1)){
                [FunctionManager showMessage:@"" withMessage:@"Please Select Length" withDelegage:nil];
                return;
            }
        }
      }
      else {
          [FunctionManager showMessage:@"" withMessage:@"Please Select Method" withDelegage:nil];
          return;
      }
    }
```

[image]

its working properly when I click on `btnNext`, if no any one item is selected then it display message. but problem is When I select the both item and go in background then I comeback in the app and click on next then it display the message, but Check box already selected. why the condition is not true in that case...

[image]

Comment: you are using what radio or check button functionality...?

Comment: more code please on where you set the imageView images for the various buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Buttons selected property instead of image when click on that button for checking
like

```
if(btnTapeIn.selected)
{
      [btnTapeIn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      btnTapIn.selected =  NO;
}
else
{
      [btnTapeIn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      btnTapIn.selected = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes It will do so, because you compared `UIImage` object Like:

```
UIImage* selectedImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"];
      if ((btnILink.imageView.image == selectedImg  || btnTapeIn.imageView.image == selectedImg || btnKeraLink.imageView.image == selectedImg))
```

Every time when its came from background it sets Create new `UIImage` object So it can not be the same `object`.
So instead of comparing object`(btnILink.imageView.image == selectedImg)` take a `bool` Value it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/Brayden/UICheckbox
```

You can implement this and decrease the comparison logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare by the button's set image. Use the button's built in `selected` property for example.

```
btnTapeIn.selected = YES;
...
if(btnTapeIn.isSelected)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (IBAction)btn_GenderCheck:(id)sender {
switch ([sender tag])
{
    case 1:   //-------for Male
        [btn_malecheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn_femalecheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isMaletag=1;

        break;
    case 2: //----------for Female
        [btn_malecheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn_femalecheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isMaletag=2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

```
// then you can check tag and accordingly alert your message
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set images in for normal state and selected in `XIB` and change the state in `IBAction`